# Is the any sort of repository for OS/system dSYM files for every version of iOS, macOS, etc.?

Tags: ios, macos, symbolicatecrash, dsym, symbolicate

To fully symbolicate Apple crash files it would be nice to have all the dSYM files for all the modules (binary images) mentioned in the crash stack traces. Where do people normally get dSYM files for OS/system components of iOS, macOS, etc.? Is there any centralized repo for getting those?

Comment: If you plug to your Mac the device with the iOS version that is specified in crash log having Xcode opened, Xcode will generate symbols for that iOS version.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk, thanks! What would be the location where the symbol files will be dropped to?

Comment: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/<iOS version> (<iOS build number>)/Symbols`

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The list and download links can be found on GitHub - https://github.com/Zuikyo/iOS-System-Symbols/blob/master/collected-symbol-files.md

Unfortunately there are only iOS 13 and earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my company was using while the repo was actively maintained. But not anymore :)